# What do we do about closed questions with bad tags?

Tags: discussion, tags, closed-questions

So, [this question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/31402/wind-waker-barrier-skip-to-ganons-castle) was closed because it's a video-game question.

It's tagged with [rpg-theory](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rpg-theory) because, well, presumably the asker couldn't find any more appropriate tags and just tagged it with *something*.

So, here's the problem:

- It soooo not an [rpg-theory](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rpg-theory) question, but now it shows up at the top of the tag's question list.
- It has to have at least one tag, like every other question, so I can't remove [rpg-theory](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rpg-theory) without adding some other one.
- There *are* no appropriate tags, since it's a question about something this site doesn't cover.

Answer (score 5):

In this case, the question should be deleted after a little while.  Since the guy has seen he's OT already, I've deleted it now.  Super off topic questions should get deleted as well as closed.

In the rarer case when it's closed, shouldn't be deleted, and has bad tags - I find it hard to muster up much caring. If someone super anal wants to fix the tags, have at it.